# How to extract data from a post meta

Tags: post-meta

What is the best way to extract the information from the database using `get_post_meta`?

`field name = invoice_details`

```
value = a:20:{s:15:"price_per_night";s:3:"150";s:12:"no_of_nights";s:1:"1";s:23:"price_calulating_nights";s:3:"150";s:22:"price_after_commission";s:3:"150";s:13:"discount_type";s:0:"";s:20:"price_after_discount";s:3:"150";s:16:"discounted_price";s:1:"0";s:19:"discount_percentage";s:0:"";s:17:"total_service_fee";s:2:"60";s:11:"total_price";s:3:"210";s:8:"currency";s:3:"GBP";s:7:"post_id";s:2:"21";s:8:"check_in";s:10:"02-07-2017";s:9:"check_out";s:10:"03-07-2017";s:6:"guests";s:1:"1";s:16:"security_deposit";s:3:"100";s:10:"secret_key";s:30:"FfmtXmaPOKbrS8B1XLugufiD3Hdjxl";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2017-06-25 17:04:33";s:18:"booking_request_by";i:2;s:17:"step_2_attributes";a:9:{s:9:"firstname";s:3:"Tom";s:8:"lastname";s:5:"Smith";s:14:"street_address";s:3:"229";s:11:"postal_code";s:8:"YW11 3DU";s:4:"city";s:6:"London";s:7:"country";s:14:"United Kingdom";s:5:"phone";s:10:"0799999999";s:11:"guest_fname";a:1:{i:1;s:5:"Bella";}s:11:"guest_lname";a:1:{i:1;s:4:"King";}}}
```

For example how could I retrieve the "firstname" field as "James"?

I am currently using:

`$billing_firstname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $invoice_details['firstname'] , true );`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Unserialized value:

```
array (
  'price_per_night' => '150',
  'no_of_nights' => '1',
  'price_calulating_nights' => '150',
  'price_after_commission' => '150',
  'discount_type' => '',
  'price_after_discount' => '150',
  'discounted_price' => '0',
  'discount_percentage' => '',
  'total_service_fee' => '60',
  'total_price' => '210',
  'currency' => 'GBP',
  'post_id' => '21',
  'check_in' => '02-07-2017',
  'check_out' => '03-07-2017',
  'guests' => '1',
  'security_deposit' => '100',
  'secret_key' => 'FfmtXmaPOKbrS8B1XLugufiD3Hdjxl',
  'updated_at' => '2017-06-25 17:04:33',
  'booking_request_by' => 2,
  'step_2_attributes' => 
  array (
    'firstname' => 'Tom',
    'lastname' => 'Smith',
    'street_address' => '229',
    'postal_code' => 'YW11 3DU',
    'city' => 'London',
    'country' => 'United Kingdom',
    'phone' => '0799999999',
    'guest_fname' => 
    array (
      1 => 'Bella',
    ),
    'guest_lname' => 
    array (
      1 => 'King',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried online unserializer tool, but failed to interpret your value, because it's broken.

Anyway, the way to get value is like below:

```
// Get the value from db first
$meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'invoice_details' , true ); //'invoice_details' is a string, not a variable

// Get to the desired value
$desired_value = $meta_value['array_key']; // value from first step of array
```

or:

```
$desired_value = $meta_value['array_key']['array_key_second']; // value from second step of array
```

You should `var_dump($meta_value)` after having `$meta_value` to get the idea how to proceed with the data.

## Edit

I simply organized your array like below:

```
<?php
array (
    'price_per_night' => '150',
    'no_of_nights' => '1',
    'price_calulating_nights' => '150',
    'price_after_commission' => '150',
    'discount_type' => '',
    'price_after_discount' => '150',
    'discounted_price' => '0',
    'discount_percentage' => '',
    'total_service_fee' => '60',
    'total_price' => '210',
    'currency' => 'GBP',
    'post_id' => '21',
    'check_in' => '02-07-2017',
    'check_out' => '03-07-2017',
    'guests' => '1',
    'security_deposit' => '100',
    'secret_key' => 'FfmtXmaPOKbrS8B1XLugufiD3Hdjxl',
    'updated_at' => '2017-06-25 17:04:33',
    'booking_request_by' => 2,
    'step_2_attributes' => array (
        'firstname' => 'Tom',
        'lastname' => 'Smith',
        'street_address' => '229',
        'postal_code' => 'YW11 3DU',
        'city' => 'London',
        'country' => 'United Kingdom',
        'phone' => '0799999999',
        'guest_fname' => array (
            1 => 'Bella',
        ),
        'guest_lname' => array (
            1 => 'King',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And it itself giving you the answer. Yes, just get to the nested keys:

```
$firstname = $meta_value['step_2_attributes']['firstname'];
```

If the `'firstname'` is *set* you will get the First Name.

For Guest First Name:

```
$guestFirstname = $meta_value['step_2_attributes']['guest_fname'][1];
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, how do I know what the array_key for firstname? I have used the online unserializer to interpret value, please see the original description

Comment: I have updated the value which can be interpretted when using online unserializer tool

Comment: Updated my answer